# How to update list of offered watchOS complications dynamically

Tags: watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

In my watch app the `AppIntentRecommendation` that is returned by `func recommendations()` needs to be updated after the app is launched.

**Problem**: The information that I need to return a list of `AppIntentRecommendation` is not available when the app is first installed, so I return a "dummy" `AppIntentRecommendation` initially. After the app is launched for the first time and user has signed in, I can update the `AppIntentRecommendation` in `func recommendations()` but watchOS does not update the list of widgets presented as complications.

```
    func recommendations() -> [AppIntentRecommendation<ConfigurationAppIntent>] {
        // Create an array with all the preconfigured widgets to show.
        let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.myApp")!
        guard let names = defaults.dictionary(forKey: "names" as? [String:String] else {
            return [AppIntentRecommendation(intent: .Demo, description: "Demo")]
        }

        var recs = [AppIntentRecommendation<ConfigurationAppIntent>]()
        for (idx, name) in names() {
            let rec = ConfigurationAppIntent()
            rec.order = idx
            rec.carName = name
            rec.action = nil
            recs.append(AppIntentRecommendation(intent: rec, description: "name") )
        }
        return recs
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is easy but it's deep in the documentation:

`WidgetCenter.shared.invalidateConfigurationRecommendations()`

This will reload the recommendations

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where, how to satisfy 
```func recommendations() -> [AppIntentRecommendation<ConfigurationAppIntent>] {}```

Comment: Once you invalidate using the line in the response, watchOS will updated the new complications in your `func recommendations()`